# Jquery - Own jquery ui stack function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, stack

I try to exclude the jquery ui stack function

**JS Code**

```
 stack('myStack');

 function stack(selector)
 {
    var group = $.makeArray(selector).sort(function(a,b) {
            return (parseInt($(a).css("zIndex"),10) || 0) - (parseInt($(b).css("zIndex"),10) || 0);
    });
    if (!group.length) { return; }

    var min = parseInt(group[0].style.zIndex) || 0;
    $(group).each(function(i) {
            this.style.zIndex = min + i;
    });

    this[0].style.zIndex = min + group.length;

 }
```

i get the error `group[0].style is undefined`. The div's with the selector `".myStack"` exists.
Hope someone can help me.

Thanks in advance!
Peter

---

**EDIT: jquery ui code**

```
$.ui.plugin.add("draggable", "stack", {
    start: function(event, ui) {

        var o = $(this).data("draggable").options;

        var group = $.makeArray($(o.stack)).sort(function(a,b) {
            return (parseInt($(a).css("zIndex"),10) || 0) - (parseInt($(b).css("zIndex"),10) || 0);
        });
        if (!group.length) { return; }

        var min = parseInt(group[0].style.zIndex) || 0;
        $(group).each(function(i) {
            this.style.zIndex = min + i;
        });

        this[0].style.zIndex = min + group.length;

    }
});
```

---

**EDIT:** http://jsfiddle.net/ugfFU/4/

**HTML**

```
<div style="background-color:#ff0000;" class="dragStack test"></div>
<div style="background-color:#00aa00;" class="dragStack test"></div>
<div style="background-color:#ff00aa;" class="dragStack test"></div>
<div style="background-color:#0000aa;" class="dragStack test"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {


$(".test").draggable({
        addClasses: false,
        start: function(event, ui) {  },
        stop:  function(event, ui) {  }
    })
    .mouseup(function(data, handler)
    {
       stacker(this,'.dragStack');
    });
 });


 function stacker(thisA,selector)
 {
    var group = $(selector).get().sort(function(a, b) {
        return ((parseInt(a.style.zIndex), 10) || 0)-((parseInt(b.style.zIndex), 10) || 0);
    });

    if (!group.length) {
         return;
    }

    var min = parseInt(group[0].style.zIndex) || 0;
    $.each(group, function(i) {
        this.style.zIndex = min + i;
        $(this).css('z-index',''+this.style.zIndex+'');
    });

    $(thisA).css('z-index',''+min + group.length+'');

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$.makeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/) does not do what you think it does: it turns array-like objects into "real" arrays, but doesn't resolve selectors.

Try using [get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/) or [toArray()](http://api.jquery.com/toArray/) instead:

```
function stack(selector)
{
    var group = $(selector).get().sort(function(a, b) {
        return (parseInt(a.style.zIndex), 10) || 0)
             - (parseInt(b.style.zIndex), 10) || 0);
    });

    if (!group.length) {
        return;
    }

    var min = parseInt(group[0].style.zIndex) || 0;
    $.each(group, function(i) {
        this.style.zIndex = min + i;
    });

    // Not sure about the line below, depends on the context the function
    // is called in.
    this.style.zIndex = min + group.length;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer.  Now i get the error this[0] is undefined.

Comment: @Peter, that's what I was saying in the code comment in my answer. Using `this` there doesn't make much sense unless all callers of `stack` use something like `$.proxy()`. What is that line of code supposed to do?

Comment: @Peter, from the code in your updated question, removing the `[0]` indexer might fix your problem.

Comment: I understand, the problem ist that i dont send the current clicked element to the function. I build a little example, it works, but the order ist not really correct. -> http://jsfiddle.net/ugfFU/4/